# Page navigation on touch, in PhoneGap application for Android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm making a PhoneGap application for the Android platform. I want page navigation from left to right and right to left on touch movement. Can you help me how can I do this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the research that you have done? Have you written some code?

Comment: Sorry Sir, nothing is done yet. Because I've no idea how to do this..

Comment: Start from here: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494774/Getting%20started%20with%20Android%20PhoneGap%20in%20Eclipse and follow the tutorials. Work something up, and then ask for help.

Comment: I believe you are starting fresh with this approach, so to start with have a look at jQuery Mobile. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html#../../ this should give some idea.

Comment: Thanku sir.
I've done it. app is running.
But i want page sliding in the app as right to left and left to right as in android which is done by using by the gesture. Means page navigation on finfure touch right to left and left to right.

Thanks for help me.
Preet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow those tutorials. But you do the animations with CSS. By adding classnames. This is what I have in my image carousel for sliding images from right to left.

Thus, to answer your question:
1. Get familiar with touch code and "fast button"
2. Learn about keyframes in CSS.

```
/*   Transitions   */
.sliding .in {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideinfromright;
}
.sliding .out {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideouttoleft;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideinfromright {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideouttoleft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help me.
Please tell me where i've to mention the class name.

Comment: You add the classnames to the view wrapper. Usually body < section.